# Moved Permanently error when calling a PHP WebService from .NET

Tags: c#, php, .net, web-services, wsdl

I have developed a WebService in PHP... it works perfectly when I call it from a PHP application, but I have problems when calling from .NET.

The error I am received when I call a web method is "Moved Permanently".

The WSDL of the service is at: http://feriados.servicios.desytec.com/feriados?wsdl

And the .NET code is the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Servicio.Desytec_Feriados svc = new Servicio.Desytec_Feriados();
    var feriados = svc.GetHolidays("8cd4c502f69b5606a8bef291deaac1ba83bb9876", "cl", "2014", "5");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(feriados.Length);
}
```

Comment: That likely means your webservice is redirecting URLs....if you're using System.Net.HttpWebRequest or System.Net.WebClient see if there's a way to automatically follow redirects....or check if the status is moved permanently (status code 301)...and check the response headers to follow the URL

Comment: there are no redirects... and as I said, the webservice works when called from a PHP web page. If you use the WSDL url, the XML document is correctly displayed.

Comment: "The error I am received when I call a web method is 'Moved Permanently'. Clearly, you're getting something other than a status 200 OK. Do you think .NET is lying about the status? You're probably getting 301...PHP will probably automatically follow redirect headers, but dot net doesn't. Can you post your code that's actually using the WebClient or HttpRequest class?

Comment: How can I find that code? When I add the Webservice reference, it adds a Reference.cs file, which contains a class derived from SoapHttpClientProtocol. inside of it, a call to Invoke actually calls the actual method.

Comment: Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It was due because the URL of the WSDL was bad specified. It was written as http://destec.com/app.php/feriados, but the correct is http://destec.com/feriados, because .htaccess is stripping the app.php part (the webservice was programmed using Symfony PHP framework).

Regards
Jaime